# Finding out antenna gain in 3-D space (azimuth and elevation)

Tags: antenna, gain

I found a cross-sectional view of a patch antenna's gain below. I would like to know how can I determine the antenna's gain for every azimuth and elevation angle in 3-D space?

[image]

Comment: From the information provided, you simply cannot.  It *may* be that the pattern is rotationally symmetric about the axis of "aim" but there's no information here to state that, and the visible left/right asymmetry in the plot suggests it is probably is not the case, though it could potentially be close.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - do you have any experience with testing antenna gains in real-world condition, if so you stated it could be potentially close. How close is it between simulation and the real world?

Comment: Its actually very hard to build a good setup for such a test, as you not only need a suitable receiver and antenna, but also either an anechoic chamber or a large volume of quiet empty space, ie, in some cases putting it on a poll in the middle of a field might work, especially if the poll matches however it would be mounted in actual use.

Comment: My question is: why do you need the gain for every azimuth and angle? (this information is usually not very interesting)

Comment: @StefanWyss the Friis equation with is used to calculate the power received by a receiver is calculated using the gain of the transmitter as a function of its azimuth and elevation angles. Hence depending on what particular angle the receiver is at in 3D space I need to the corresponding gain for that particular angle. Therefore I need to know the gain for every azimuth and its corresponding elevation angle.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram doesn't provide any information about how the gain varies as a function of azimuth, but for many analysis purposes with most patch antennas you can just assume the beam pattern is symmetric about the boresight axis - i.e. provided your "azimuth" and "elevation" are defined with respect to the antenna orientation, just discard the azimuth parameter and look up the elevation into a table derived from one half of the plot you showed.

This will usually be within a dB or two, at least within the region of the main lobe (approximately the -3dB beam width region indicated in red). Anyway in real life the gain pattern is influenced to at least that extent by the surrounding geometry of whatever it's mounted to; those effects can be simulated but would require more data on the antenna construction to do so.

Comment: do you have any experience with testing antenna gains in real-world condition, if so how close is it between simulation and the real world?

Comment: Yes, plenty; it depends on the quality of your simulation! Getting better than about 1 dB modeling accuracy requires a lot of effort.